# SharePoint 2016 - Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I'm getting the dreaded Server Error in '/' Application all of a sudden, sharepoint is completely down, including Central Administration. The only recent changes were 3 updates applied this morning during our monthly patch cycle.

- Cumulative Update 7 (KB 3092423) for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server
- May 8, 2018—KB4103723 (OS Build 14393.2248)
- 2018-05 Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based Systems (KB4132216)

Here are the errors thrown when trying to access sharepoint or Central Administration:

Log Name:      Application
Source:        ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0
Date:          5/29/2018 7:24:13 PM
Event ID:      1309
Task Category: Web Event
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      SHAREPOINT.SHTC.AD
Description:
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 5/29/2018 7:24:13 PM 
Event time (UTC): 5/30/2018 1:24:13 AM 
Event ID: af53fe92a5654d0f9fd8b9344b66ac54 
Event sequence: 2 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1562424988/ROOT-1-131721170323451059 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\45071\ 
    Machine name: SHAREPOINT

Process information: 
    Process ID: 11020 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: SHTCPLANT\spdbadmin

Exception information: 
    Exception type: TargetInvocationException 
    Exception message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAutoSerializingObject.GetInstanceFromType(Type type, String typename)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFileSystemCache.FetchObjectFromFileSystem(Guid id, Boolean idFieldsOnly, Guid& objParentId)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFileSystemCache.GetValue(Guid id)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPCache`2.get_Item(K key)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.GetObject(Guid id, Boolean checkInMemoryCache, Boolean checkFileSystemCache, Boolean checkDatabase)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPPersistedStoreProvider.GetObject(Guid id)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObjectCollection`1.get_Item(Guid objId)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObjectCollection`1.d__0.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.LookupContextWebApplication()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.Lookup(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, Boolean fallbackToHttpContext, Boolean skipFillFileSystemCache, SPAlternateUrl& alternateUrl, ISPSiteLookupInfo& hostHeaderSiteInfo, Boolean& lookupRequiredContext)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupSiteInfo(SPFarm farm, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, Uri& requestUri, Boolean& lookupRequiredContext, Guid& applicationId, Guid& contentDatabaseId, Guid& siteId, Guid& siteSubscriptionId, SPUrlZone& zone, String& serverRelativeUrl, Boolean& hostHeaderIsSiteName, Boolean& appWebRequest, String& appHostHeaderRedirectDomain, String& appSiteDomainPrefix, String& subscriptionName, String& appSiteDomainId, Uri& primaryUri)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, SPUserToken userToken)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAlternateUrl.GetContextUri(HttpContext ctx)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAppRequestContext.InitCurrent(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAppRequestContext.get_Current()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, SPAppPrincipalToken appPrincipalToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRequestManager.GetContextRequest(SPRequestAuthenticationMode authenticationMode)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.get_RequestAny()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPLanguageSettings.GetGlobalInstalledLanguages(Int32 compatibilityLevel)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTemplateFileSystemWatcher.RefreshInstalledLocales()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTemplateFileSystemWatcher.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.System.Web.IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)

The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Administration.ProjectEventService' threw an exception.
   at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Administration.ProjectEventService..ctor()

Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)
   at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Administration.ProjectEventService..cctor()

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://sharepoint:3014/ 
    Request path: / 
    User host address: fe80::d9ad:c12e:3b88:7155/29/2018 7:24:13 PM 
    User:
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:
    Thread account name: SHTCPLANT\spdbadmin

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 13 
    Thread account name: SHTCPLANT\spdbadmin 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAutoSerializingObject.GetInstanceFromType(Type type, String typename)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFileSystemCache.FetchObjectFromFileSystem(Guid id, Boolean idFieldsOnly, Guid& objParentId)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFileSystemCache.GetValue(Guid id)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPCache`2.get_Item(K key)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.GetObject(Guid id, Boolean checkInMemoryCache, Boolean checkFileSystemCache, Boolean checkDatabase)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPPersistedStoreProvider.GetObject(Guid id)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObjectCollection`1.get_Item(Guid objId)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObjectCollection`1.d__0.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.LookupContextWebApplication()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.Lookup(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, Boolean fallbackToHttpContext, Boolean skipFillFileSystemCache, SPAlternateUrl& alternateUrl, ISPSiteLookupInfo& hostHeaderSiteInfo, Boolean& lookupRequiredContext)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupSiteInfo(SPFarm farm, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, Uri& requestUri, Boolean& lookupRequiredContext, Guid& applicationId, Guid& contentDatabaseId, Guid& siteId, Guid& siteSubscriptionId, SPUrlZone& zone, String& serverRelativeUrl, Boolean& hostHeaderIsSiteName, Boolean& appWebRequest, String& appHostHeaderRedirectDomain, String& appSiteDomainPrefix, String& subscriptionName, String& appSiteDomainId, Uri& primaryUri)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, SPUserToken userToken)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAlternateUrl.GetContextUri(HttpContext ctx)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAppRequestContext.InitCurrent(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAppRequestContext.get_Current()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, SPAppPrincipalToken appPrincipalToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRequestManager.GetContextRequest(SPRequestAuthenticationMode authenticationMode)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.get_RequestAny()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPLanguageSettings.GetGlobalInstalledLanguages(Int32 compatibilityLevel)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTemplateFileSystemWatcher.RefreshInstalledLocales()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTemplateFileSystemWatcher.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.System.Web.IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)

Custom event details:

Event Xml:

  
    
    1309
    3
    3
    0x80000000000000
    
    10657
    Application
    SHAREPOINT.SHTC.AD
    
  
  
    3005
    An unhandled exception has occurred.
    5/29/2018 7:24:13 PM
    5/30/2018 1:24:13 AM
    af53fe92a5654d0f9fd8b9344b66ac54
    2
    1
    0
    /LM/W3SVC/1562424988/ROOT-1-131721170323451059
    Full
    /
    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\45071\
    SHAREPOINT
    
    
    11020
    w3wp.exe
    SHTCPLANT\spdbadmin
    TargetInvocationException
    Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAutoSerializingObject.GetInstanceFromType(Type type, String typename)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFileSystemCache.FetchObjectFromFileSystem(Guid id, Boolean idFieldsOnly, Guid& objParentId)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFileSystemCache.GetValue(Guid id)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPCache`2.get_Item(K key)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.GetObject(Guid id, Boolean checkInMemoryCache, Boolean checkFileSystemCache, Boolean checkDatabase)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPPersistedStoreProvider.GetObject(Guid id)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObjectCollection`1.get_Item(Guid objId)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObjectCollection`1.<GetEnumeratorImpl>d__0.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.LookupContextWebApplication()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.Lookup(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, Boolean fallbackToHttpContext, Boolean skipFillFileSystemCache, SPAlternateUrl& alternateUrl, ISPSiteLookupInfo& hostHeaderSiteInfo, Boolean& lookupRequiredContext)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupSiteInfo(SPFarm farm, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, Uri& requestUri, Boolean& lookupRequiredContext, Guid& applicationId, Guid& contentDatabaseId, Guid& siteId, Guid& siteSubscriptionId, SPUrlZone& zone, String& serverRelativeUrl, Boolean& hostHeaderIsSiteName, Boolean& appWebRequest, String& appHostHeaderRedirectDomain, String& appSiteDomainPrefix, String& subscriptionName, String& appSiteDomainId, Uri& primaryUri)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, SPUserToken userToken)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAlternateUrl.GetContextUri(HttpContext ctx)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAppRequestContext.InitCurrent(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAppRequestContext.get_Current()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, SPAppPrincipalToken appPrincipalToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRequestManager.GetContextRequest(SPRequestAuthenticationMode authenticationMode)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.get_RequestAny()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPLanguageSettings.GetGlobalInstalledLanguages(Int32 compatibilityLevel)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTemplateFileSystemWatcher.RefreshInstalledLocales()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTemplateFileSystemWatcher.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.System.Web.IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)

The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Administration.ProjectEventService' threw an exception.
   at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Administration.ProjectEventService..ctor()

Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)
   at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Administration.ProjectEventService..cctor()

http://sharepoint:3014/
    /
    fe80::d9ad:c12e:3b88:715%3
    
    
    False
    
    
    SHTCPLANT\spdbadmin
    13
    SHTCPLANT\spdbadmin
    False
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAutoSerializingObject.GetInstanceFromType(Type type, String typename)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFileSystemCache.FetchObjectFromFileSystem(Guid id, Boolean idFieldsOnly, Guid& objParentId)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFileSystemCache.GetValue(Guid id)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPCache`2.get_Item(K key)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.GetObject(Guid id, Boolean checkInMemoryCache, Boolean checkFileSystemCache, Boolean checkDatabase)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPPersistedStoreProvider.GetObject(Guid id)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObjectCollection`1.get_Item(Guid objId)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObjectCollection`1.<GetEnumeratorImpl>d__0.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.LookupContextWebApplication()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.Lookup(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, Boolean fallbackToHttpContext, Boolean skipFillFileSystemCache, SPAlternateUrl& alternateUrl, ISPSiteLookupInfo& hostHeaderSiteInfo, Boolean& lookupRequiredContext)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupSiteInfo(SPFarm farm, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, Uri& requestUri, Boolean& lookupRequiredContext, Guid& applicationId, Guid& contentDatabaseId, Guid& siteId, Guid& siteSubscriptionId, SPUrlZone& zone, String& serverRelativeUrl, Boolean& hostHeaderIsSiteName, Boolean& appWebRequest, String& appHostHeaderRedirectDomain, String& appSiteDomainPrefix, String& subscriptionName, String& appSiteDomainId, Uri& primaryUri)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite, Boolean swapSchemeForPathBasedSites, SPUserToken userToken)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAlternateUrl.GetContextUri(HttpContext ctx)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAppRequestContext.InitCurrent(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAppRequestContext.get_Current()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, SPAppPrincipalToken appPrincipalToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRequestManager.GetContextRequest(SPRequestAuthenticationMode authenticationMode)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.get_RequestAny()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPLanguageSettings.GetGlobalInstalledLanguages(Int32 compatibilityLevel)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTemplateFileSystemWatcher.RefreshInstalledLocales()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTemplateFileSystemWatcher.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.System.Web.IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)

Log Name:      Application
Source:        .NET Runtime
Date:          5/29/2018 7:25:54 PM
Event ID:      1023
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      SHAREPOINT.SHTC.AD
Description:
Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 00007FFC98AE79E9 (00007FFC98AD0000) with exit code 80131506.

Event Xml:

  
    
    1023
    2
    0
    0x80000000000000
    
    10659
    Application
    SHAREPOINT.SHTC.AD
    
  
  
    Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 00007FFC98AE79E9 (00007FFC98AD0000) with exit code 80131506.

Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          5/29/2018 7:25:54 PM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      SHAREPOINT.SHTC.AD
Description:
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x57899b8a
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.7.2650.0, time stamp: 0x5ab1c520
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000179e9
Faulting process id: 0x2b0c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3f7b4dd17fde4
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 6ac9285d-ea97-41f7-abb7-94dcda784345
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event Xml:

  
    
    1000
    2
    100
    0x80000000000000
    
    10660
    Application
    SHAREPOINT.SHTC.AD
    
  
  
    w3wp.exe
    10.0.14393.0
    57899b8a
    clr.dll
    4.7.2650.0
    5ab1c520
    c0000005
    00000000000179e9
    2b0c
    01d3f7b4dd17fde4
    c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
    6ac9285d-ea97-41f7-abb7-94dcda784345

I've installed the Debug Diagnostic tool and set the crashdump rule to the Sharepoint - 80 and Sharepoint Central Administration v4 app pools, the reports 
are massive, I'm totally lost. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a permission issue on DB. Are you able to access the SP DB using the  SHTCPLANT\spdbadmin ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check if "SHTCPLANT\spdbadmin" account is still working properly? try logging in that account to you SQL using SSMS to check its permission.

Answer (score 0):

w3wp.exe is IIS worker process (app pool). so this is happening because of something is being processed in IIS. consult IIS log files to find after what request this event log happens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; the spdbadmin account has access to the DB, nothing changed there. I did dig this up from the AppCrash_w3wp.exe report:

Comment: Found the issue, turned out to the the SCOM agent APM; using the debug tool I created a crashdump which lead me to this error and subsequently this site on how to resolve it.  system.IO.FileLoadException Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401) System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1). http://sp2013.pro/2017/03/loading-assembly-produce-different-grant-set-instances/#more-625